# getting a error called 'ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type' when passing a variable through an sqlite query

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, request

So I am trying to get a row from table and if I run something like this below...

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE social = '999-99-9999'")
elements = cursor.fetchall()

for x in elements:
   print(x)
```

it works just fine, it will show all of the elements in a row

...but if I do try to pass a variable like this below....

```
m = 999-99-9999
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE social = ?", (m))
elements = cursor.fetchall()

for x in elements:
    print(x)
```

"ValueError: parameters are of unsupported type" is the error I get from doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to use a string for the `m` local variable, and then use `string.format()` to format the SQL query with `m`.

```
m = "999-99-9999"
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE social = '{}'".format(m))
```

PS: Congratulations on your first question in 5 years!